# Spotify Web API - Token Validation

Tags: spotify

Given an auth token, originally received from Spotify Android/iOS SDK, I want to check with Spotify that the token I am holding is valid. Is there a minimal endpoint for doing this?

Ideally something not data-intensive, as I just want to know if the token is valid. This must be done with Web API and not SDK.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no API endpoint for checking whether the access token is still valid. Usually you would store it along with the `expires_in` value that tells you until when it is valid.

An alternative is making a request to any endpoint from the Web API passing the access token. You will get a `401 Unauthorized` status code back if the token has expired.